# Iterate over hash and return newly formed hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm trying to iterate over hash and return new hash. My original hash is:

```
companies = {
  company_id: {
   "0": { title: "Google", address: "New str" },
   "1": { title: "Facebook", address: "Old str." },
   "2": { title: "Amazon", address: "River str." }
  }
 }
```

I want to return hash that is structured this way:

```
{
  title: "Google",
  address: "New str."
}
```

If company_id equal to "0" I would need to return details of that company, similar to below:

```
companies.each do |k,v|
  v.each do |k,v|
    if k.to_s == "0"
       title: v[:title]
       address: v[:address]
     end
   end
 end
```

Iteration above doesn't return me hash, how can I get structured hash that I need? Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to get the value from the key "0", or do to you need to map `companies` hash?

Comment: I need to map companies hash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do

```
companies[:company_id][:"0"]
# {  title: "Google",   address: "New str." }
```

Comment: He says he wants to iterate which means he has more than one Hash inside that companies hash.

Comment: He says he has an 'hash' and expects to return an 'hash'. Your assumption will return an array.

Comment: This is the correct answer. There is no need for any iteration at all. It satisfies all the requirements and passes all the tests in the question.